# Cannot deploy rest service in EBS when DB upgraded to 19c

Tags: oracle, soa

We recently upgraded our DB from 12c (12.1.0.2.0) to 19c(19.0.0.0.0) in EBS 12.1.3 environment on test instance. After upgrade I am unable to deploy custom web services using SOA rest services integration repository. I am getting following error on deployment:

**Service Provider Access resulted in exception 'oracle.apps.fnd.isg.client.IREPException' when attempting to perform 'DEPLOY'. Please view Service Provider logs for more details**

I reviewed log files but nothing informative found. One thing I noticed that I was able to deploy web services with simple out parameters with VARCHAR2 data type. But when there is an out parameter defined based on table type, I am receiving above mentioned error. I defined table type out parameter as follows which returns data in form of json array.

TYPE XRCL_TMS_PICKED_ORDERS1 IS TABLE OF ROCELL.XRCL_TMS_PICKED_ORDERS1%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

It would be better to mention that on application with 12c database, web service can be deployed with no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by finding cause of collection type compatibility in 12c and 19c versions of databases.

In 12c below declaration of plsql collection type works fine:

TYPE type_name IS TABLE OF Table_Name%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

but in 19c above declaration of plsql collection type has following error. I found this error after trying to recompile collection type:

PLS-00355: use of pl/sql table not allowed in this context

In 19c below declaration worked fine (created type as nested table):

CREATE TYPE type_name AS OBJECT

(
column_name datatype
);

CREATE TYPE type_name_nt AS TABLE OF type_name;

Comment: Hey! Do you have any references to the change from Oracle by any chance? Trying to find out any details about this change as I fear we may also be impacted!

Comment: I do not have any official note from Oracle on this issue. I just found invalid object in ALL_OBJECTS which was actually previously nested table type. It gave me clue what was wrong in api deployment.